# Shape of 2D infinitely deep potential well with the lowest ground-state energy and fixed perimeter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, ground-state

In quantum mechanics context, consider an 2D infinitely deep potential well with fixed perimeter. That is, the shape could be arbitrarily changed on condition that the perimeter is constant. Now consider the ground state energy of this shape of potential well. What's its shape when the ground state energy reaches minimum?

Intuitively I think the shape is a circle, with enough symmetry, but I don't know how to prove it.I tried many ways like Bessel function expansion and variational principle, and it didn't make sense. Or more precisely, I tried

$$\psi(r,\theta)=\sum_{l,m}A_{lm}J_l(r)e^{im\theta}$$

and the ground state energy

$$E=\int_\Omega \langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle\sim\int_\Omega|\nabla\psi|^2$$
What can I do next? It seems like a functional analysis problem?